# MySQL count rows using GROUP BY with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have 2 tables one storing the categories tree and another table with thee translations.

I want to get the number of categories that are translated.
A language is a code number from 100 to 900 (dos).
For example, the next code will return 122 for the 'dos' 100... this means that for the 100 I have 122 categories on that lang.

```
SELECT count(*) AS cats, i18n.dos
FROM `hex_articles_tree` tree 
LEFT JOIN hex_fields_i18n i18n 
ON i18n.tree_label_id = tree.id 
AND i18n.dos = 100 WHERE i18n.tree_label_id IS NOT NULL
```

The return of the query is :

```
cats | dos
122  | 100
```

So my question is how can a perform a query that will return the translation from each lang.
I will need something like:

```
cats | dos
122  | 100
96   | 120
56   | 200
```

With a simple table without translations where the 'dos' was explicit on the table I could accomplish the desired result with:

```
SELECT count(*) AS results, DOS 
FROM `hex_articles` 
GROUP BY DOS HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Any ideas how can I group the results with the left join?
Thanks

Comment: You left out `GROUP BY i18n.dos` in the first query.

Comment: Also, change your `left join` to `inner join`.